Is there an asymptotic for so-called "exponential primes"?
Prime numbers can defined as numbers $p$ for which there are no $a$ and $b$ besides $1$ and $p$ such that $p = a\cdot b$. If we define $\pi(n)$ to be the number of primes less than or equal to $n$, then the prime number theorem states that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)} = 1$, that is, the density of primes below $x$ is roughly $\dfrac{x}{\log x}.$
But what if we replace multiplication with exponentiation? Define "exponential primes" as numbers $p$ for which there are no $a$ and $b$ besides $1$ and $p$ such that $p = a^b$. The first few exponential primes are $2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11...$ (sequence $A007916$ in the OEIS). Clearly all the primes are contained in this sequence, as well as all semiprimes and many more categories of numbers. As described on the OEIS page, all integers greater than two can be represented as a power tower of members of this sequence; just as you can factor $12 = 4\cdot 3 = 2\cdot 2\cdot 3$, you can "exponentially factor" $64 = 4^3 = 2^{2^3}$. Factorization is not unique -- in the previous example, we could have also chosen to represent $64$ as $2^6$ -- which is perhaps due to the noncommutativity of exponentiation.
Regardless, my question is:

Is there an asymptotic for the density of these exponential primes? What about tetrational primes, pentational primes, etc.?

Thanks for your time!

The sum of the reciprocals of the Perfect Powers converges, so the density is $0$.  (Using Dirichlet density, of course).

here is a computation for the sum of the reciprocals of the perfect powers, though you don't need that to show convergence.  The Wikipedia article shows that the sum including duplicates like $2^4=4^2$ is $1$ and that's enough to show convergence
